# Cisco ASA l2l tunnel established, can receive pings but cannot reply

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn

I'm a bit new to managing a Cisco ASA appliance and I'm doing my best to learn, however I got a problem here.

Long story short, we are trying to connect a hospital's ADT HL7 feed to our remote servers. To do this, we are connecting a L2L tunnel via their Cisco 5510 to our Cisco 5510.

Our Cisco 5510 is connected directly to a Linux box that hosts our Mirth HL7 interface.

Tunnel has been established, however they cannot connect their interface to ours. They also cannot telnet to our device via the specified ports (7249, 7250).

I think related to this problem is that they can send us pings from their interface hosts to ours, but we cannot ping them back. Why is this one way pinging occurring?

Here's a dump of the ASA configurations.

access-list Customer-access-list extended permit ip host 10.253.253.254 host 172.16.25.6

access-list Customer-access-list extended permit ip host 10.253.253.254 host 172.16.25.7

access-list Customer-access-list extended permit ip host 10.253.253.254 host 172.16.25.8

access-list Customer-access-list extended permit ip 10.253.253.0 255.255.255.0 host 172.16.25.8

access-list Customer-filter-acl extended permit icmp any any

access-list Customer-filter-acl extended permit tcp host 172.16.25.6 host 10.253.253.254 eq 7249

access-list Customer-filter-acl extended permit tcp host 172.16.25.6 host 10.253.253.254 eq 7250

access-list Customer-filter-acl extended permit tcp host 172.16.25.7 host 10.253.253.254 eq 7249

access-list Customer-filter-acl extended permit tcp host 172.16.25.7 host 10.253.253.254 eq 7250

access-list Customer-filter-acl extended permit tcp host 172.16.25.8 host 10.253.253.254 eq 7249

access-list Customer-filter-acl extended permit tcp host 172.16.25.8 host 10.253.253.254 eq 7250